# How do you find where an SharePoint auto notification came from?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

My issue is trying to locate where an auto notification is coming from that was sent out but ran out of ideas on other ways to try. So I have a couple users that received an auto notification from SharePoint and need it to stop. I have checked to see if there are workflows or alerts setup under a site collection via poweshell cause this auto notification has an excel attachment that shows it is pulling info from different subsites and their lists but cannot find anything matching what was received via email. Is there another way?

Help?

[image: email notification]

Comment: What is the exact account that sends the notification? Sharepoint will use a different account than PowerAutomate.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? What is the "From" email address/name in notification.

Comment: The account this is received from is SPS Admin. This is for SharePoint 2016 (on-prem).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this notifications are sent by built-in SharePoint mechanism?
Could you attach screenshot of any notification in question?

It could be any kind of **code**, **server script** or **SSRS report subscription** that pulling info from SharePoint sites and send it using SharePoint outgoing e-mail settings. Depending of SMTP server settings, it could be anything that sends e-mails on behalf of SP account.

Comment: I've attached a screen shot of the notification up above... I've checked timer jobs, workflows in SPD, Alerts... just left scratching my head now on other places to check.

Comment: It definitely does not look like built-in SharePoint notification. It can be any kind of custom solution or script, running from any place. Do you have SMTP feature installed on SharePoint server? Or sending mail right via some kind of corporate mail server? I would start from reviewing Outgoing e-mail settings in Central Administration, then ask for mail server admin to check SMTP logs on server specified in this settings. To make sure that mail is sending from SharePoint Server, not any other place. If so, then start to look for any ps1-scripts and scheduled tasks on this SP server.

Comment: Sorry to bug with questions! But would running something like "Get-ScheduledJob" work? I tried running it but nothing appears and I'm unsure how to go about searching for particular ps1 scripts as I don't know the name... I've been researching this but no luck per my understanding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From my understaning, this can only be done manually by going through all the intended locations (as I described above). But to be sure that you search on the right server, you must first make sure (by SMTP logs with the help of the mail administrator) that those emails are sent from this particular server. So start from SMTP mail logs.